# Does gaining upvotes on a question/ answer increase its visibility on SO?

Tags: support, questions, voting

When a question is upvoted, comments and answers, make a question more prominent to other users who are browsing SO?

Comment: Well, if a question has a low enough score it stops being shown on the homepage, so it's important to have enough upvotes to not have that happen if you want good visibility.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense. "When a question is upvoted, comments and answers"?

Comment: @Servy will a question stay on the home page long enough for a vote to affect its placement there? Maybe true on niche sites but, I suspect, [not here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest). Right now, the oldest question is 7 minutes old, the lowest score is -1 and the highest score is 1.

Comment: ...and now there's a question which, at least for the moment, is on the home page in spite of [its score of -4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749124/thread-3-nullpointerexception-error). So, I question that votes can really have any meaningful impact on the homepage.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Keep in mind that the front page _is_ cached for a short time, as producing it is kind of expensive - people do sometimes down vote faster than a post is ultimately evicted, but they don't stay around for very long.

Answer (score 3):

Only if they perform a search and order by votes. Examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Answer (score 1):

Browsing is going to be different for everyone, as everyone has their own sets of favorite ignored and possibly *predicted* tags. The selection that goes into the front page is based on *many* decisions the system makes based on what it thinks you find interesting. Posts that the system can be sure are *really bad* aren't likely to stay there for long. I think what you're talking about is probably *searching* instead of casual browsing.

When you search, *relevance* is probably the most important thing to you. Voting has no bearing on how well a question fits your particular query, just on the perceived quality of the posts. In order to make votes help ensure that the first result was the question that most closely matched your own, folks would have to vote *on* how well that question relates to your query.

That's not to say it's not considered, if two questions seemed equally relevant to a search phrase by the tags and other specifiers given, the question scoring +21 is *very* likely to be more helpful to you than the question scoring -19.

For best results, be very specific about what you want the system to show you using some of the [awesome search modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) we make available:

```
[c][linux][fuse] is:answer ioctl on fuse body:"O_DIRECT" score:1
```

There, I'm telling the system:

> *Show me answers to a question tagged C and Linux and Fuse about ioctl on fuse where the word O_DIRECT is mentioned in the body of the answer, with at least a score of 1*

It's a silly example I just came up with to find a *very* specific question that I knew existed after finding it just a week ago, but it shows you how you can really tune the posts you find when you're looking for something specific. You can then sort the results as a whole as Aaron mentioned, which *hopefully* takes you right to several posts containing what you need.

Then, naturally, you'd examine the answers in order - first by the one that's accepted (if applicable), then by votes.

You might not have realized that you asked a rather interesting question :)